# Codeigniter action form not working

Tags: php, forms, file, codeigniter, action

I try to understand why my form action is not taking me to the controller...I press the update button on my modal, which should update info on modal to the database...and when I press it, nothing happens, no error , no message, it just close the modal and that's it. HELP PLS !!!. Here is my code:

FORM

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">

 <div class="modal-content">

<h3 class="center-align">Actualizar registro</h3>

<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12" id="update_form"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" action ="<?= base_url()?>admin/update_politic">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="update_name" type="text"  name="name" class="validate">
          <label for="first_name">Nombre</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="update_last_name" name="lastname"  type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="last_name">Apellido</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="update_side" type="text"  name="side" class="validate">
          <label for="partido">Partido</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="update_charge" type="text"  name="charge" class="validate">
          <label for="cargo">Cargo</label>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
               <div class="file-field input-field no-margin-top">
                  <div class="btn light-blue darken-4">
                    <span>Animación/Imagen</span>
                    <input type="file" name="animation_file">
                  </div>
                  <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                    <input class="file-path validate" id="animation" name="animation" type="text">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s6">
            <select id="update_section"  name="section" autocomplete="off">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
              <option value="1">Presidencia</option>
              <option value="2">Senadores</option>
              <option value="3">Diputados</option>
            </select>
            <label>Sección</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="update_politic_hide" id="update_politic_hdn" value="">
        <div class="row">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light light-blue darken-4" id="submit_update" type="submit" name="action">Actualizar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function update_politic(){

  echo "entreeeeeeee";
              if (empty($_FILES['animation_file']['name']))//Compruebo si el array $_files no tiene ningun valor en  su elemento name
              {
               //El metodo obtenerImagen me retorna los valores de dicho id
                  $data = $this->politic->get_file_name($this->input->post('update_politic_hide'));
                  $imagen = $data->POLITIC_FILE;//recupero el nombre de la imagen
                 }
                 else{
                  //en caso exista algun valor se procede a subir
                  $this->load->library("upload");
                  $config['upload_path'] = "./public/uploads/";
                  $config['allowed_types'] = "*";
                  $config['max_size'] = "500000";
                  $config['max_width'] = "2000";
                  $config['max_height'] = "2000";


                  if (!$this->upload->do_upload("animation")) {
                    $data['uploadError'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                  }
                  else {

                  $file_info = $this->upload->data();
                  $params["name"] = $this->input->post("name");
                  $params["lastname"] = $this->input->post("lastname");
                  $params["side"] = $this->input->post("side");
                  $params["charge"] = $this->input->post("charge");
                  $params["animation"] = $file_info['file_name'];
                  $params["section"] = $this->input->post("section");

                  if ($params["section"]=="Presidencia") {
                      $params["section"]=1;
                  }

                  if ($params["section"]=="Senadores") {
                      $params["section"]=2;
                  }

                  if ($params["section"]=="Diputados") {
                      $params["section"]=3;
                  }

                  $this->load->model("politic");
                  $this->politic->update($params);
                }

              }
}
```

Comment: You could try and use the form helper.  And then use the form_open_multipart() http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart

Comment: Does your form url show a IP address in url if it does you need to set your config.php base_url. another check http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: No it's ok everything...I have used base url in other sections of the project and no problem .

Comment: Can you please check you have added `extends CI_Controller` in Controller create.

Comment: check in your config file `$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;` change value to `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'admin/update_politic' , array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-groups-bordered validate', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>
```

Comment: Not working yet =( ...I try your solution and nothing, no message, no error , nothing .

Comment: use <input type="submit" name= "submit" /> instead of button

Comment: Check opening and closing of form properly

Comment: view page source?

Comment: Try This <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'admin/update_politic' , array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-groups-bordered validate', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>

Answer (score 0):

You have used `base_url()?>admin/update_politic` for submitting your form. But you have not mentioned about that controller. If you have admin controller then it will be ok. Otherwise, this is the reason for this submission.

Comment: I have the admin controller created =(

Comment: The funcion update_politic is a method inside admin controller.

Comment: I have tested your code & found it's submitting to admin controller without any problem. turn on your error reporting, then you can diagnose that error quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of button use <`input type = "submit"` value ="Submit" class="your class name here">